# Is there a way to truncate data for a getstream app via the API?

Tags: getstream-io

This is more for automated testing purposes.  I was wondering if there was a way to truncate data programmatically (to be run in a continuous integration environment).

I am trying to setup a scenario where I create a user, add a bunch of activities to the feed, but then reset everything back to zero after the tests are done.

Answer (score 1):

The current version of Stream API (v1.0) do not allow you to perform administrative actions such as feed truncation. A very common approach to test Stream integration is to stub API requests with the expected response.